# PHP trim() removing S when it's not specified

Tags: php

*Using PHP 7.2.8*

I have a strange situation regarding the `trim()` function in PHP. To exemplify, lets say I make this statement:

```
echo trim("sacas",",\s");
```

I get

```
aca
```

as a result. Further, if I make a slightly different call:

```
echo trim("  sacas",",\s")
```

I get

```
  saca
```

(if it's hard to see, the leading spaces are still there).

As best as I can tell, what is happening is that `trim`, which removes all leading and trailing characters that match a specified set, is removing all `s` characters, and ignoring whitespace. However `/s` is supposed to represent whitespace characters, and not match `s` at all.

Any ideas why this is happening? And if so, how can I remove the whitespace while leaving the `s` characters?

*As a note, my problem requires that I trim both commas AND whitespace out, so I can't simply just use trim() with no extra arguments, which does leave `s` alone*

Comment: In your second example you used a forward slash, instead of a backslash: \. So it has to be: \s.

Comment: the second param is _not_ a regular expression. `\s` is not [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). So it'll cut every \ and `s` in the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: That was just a typo on my part when writing the question.

Comment: `trim(" sacas,", " ,\t")` will do I suppose. But preg_replace might be better if you want to cut _every_ whitespace, not only surrounding whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify all the characters you want to strip (that is, you cannot use regular expression). So, to trim whitespaces and commas, you need:

```
echo trim("  sacas", ", \t\n\r\0\x0B");
```

Answer (score 3):

`trim()` accepts a a list of stripped characters – not a group, or regex.

So writing `sacas` means , `s`, `a`, `c`, `a`, and `s`.

I think you’re looking for [preg_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace('/,\s/', '', 'sacas')
```

---

Edit: From Peter’s comment, maybe something like this:

```
preg_replace('/^(,|\s)+|(,|\s)+$/', '', 'sacas')
```

Comment: Proposed regexp will also remove characters in the middle of a string

Comment: @PeterM  Completely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

To remove leading and trailing commas and spaces, you need to use `" ,"`:

```
echo trim(" , asd, asd, ,  ,", " ,");
// output: asd, asd
```

If you need to include more types of whitespace (tab, new line, form feed) you need to include them in the string, for example `" ,\t\n\r\0\x0B"`

Answer (score 0):

"As a note, my problem requires that I trim both commas AND whitespace out, so I can't simply just use trim() with no extra arguments, which does leave s alone"

This only removes leading and trailing whitespace and commas.

```
echo trim("   sacas, ",", ");
```

returns

```
sacas
```